# Generally how long is the review process for Windows Phone 7 Marketplace apps?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I'm about to upload my first application to the Windows Marketplace (Dec 2011). Generally how long is the approval process before my app appears on the Marketplace? 1 Day? 1 Week? 1 Month?

Comment: Sorry, but this seems off-topic to me, plus you'll get our answer when you upload it and get it approved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For me it's almost always 3-4 working days. Good luck with your app.

Answer (score 7):

Microsoft's [Service Level Agreement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement) (SLA) for Windows Phone Application Certification on the AppHub is **5 days**.

Answer (score 2):

It is frustratingly slow. As a developer you are used to gretting compilation results returned quickly, and interate. 
My first submission took 5 days and failed, on an icon issue. 
The time it takes should only be an issue for the first ever relaease, as with subsequent releases you can fit the time delay into your sprint cycle. The active current version will be up to 5 days behind the current development version.
There are developers that have issues because they can fail certification, and the base code has moved on already by the time the certification issue is raised.

Comment: that's why you have branching and labeling in your source-control.